# Flash Player Debugger on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bits

Tags: flash, debugging, ubuntu

I used to use Flash Player Debugger on Ubuntu 13.04, but since the update to 14.04 I cannot make it working anymore.

Is there anybody out there using Flash Debugger on Ubuntu 14.04? Does anybody know if they are compatible, since Flash Debugger hasn't receive any update for a long time now?

I've tried to setup it as usual using **nspluginwrapper**, but it simply doesn't show anything on Flash content.

Answer (score 5):

I got it working by issuing the following:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xvfb libcurl3:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxt6:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libnss3:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

I wrote a little more about it [here on my blog](http://tjajab.blogspot.se/2014/08/flashplayer-debugger-on-headless-64-bit.html)

Comment: revived my flashdebugger by following the 'long' procedure on your blog. Thanks! (You might want to include it in the answer above, in case your blogpost gets deleted)

Answer (score -1):

I got the flash debugger to work with Firefox on 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 by doing the following:

1. Install 'ia32-libs', since the Flash debugger player for Linux is 32bit, you need 32bit libraries. Since the 'ia32-libs' package has been removed from Ubuntu in 14.04, I installed the complete list by doing the following:

sudo apt-get install libc6:i386

sudo -i 
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list

apt-get update

apt-get install ia32-libs

rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ia32-libs-raring.list

apt-get update

1. Install nspluginwrapper 'sudo apt-get install nspluginwrapper'. Download the Flash Debug player (version 11.2, 32bit). Extract and copy the libflashplayer.so to /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/  (I also copied it to ~/.mozilla/plugins/).  Then run 'sudo nspluginwrapper -i /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so'
2. I copied my mm.cfg debug config file to ~/ home directory.

I originally installed several of the ia32-libraries manually, but even though the flash debug player seemed to be installed and working, any content was blank. I'm not sure which libraries were missing, but by using the raring source.list from above and installing all the remaining 32bit library support, it started working.

NOTE: I also installed the 32bit version of Firefox 'sudo apt-get install firefox:i386' but I'm not sure this was necessary to solve this issue of getting the debug player to work.... I think it would work fine with the 64bit following the above steps.... but at this point its working for me and I only use Firefox for debugging flash stuff.

Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't relevant to me. The repo (deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse) is inaccessible